# Do I need to download the entire blockchain in order to use bitcoin-cli?

Tags: development

I want to try and compile and run bitcoin-cli locally. Do I need to download the entire blockchain first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For testing, you can run your node on testnet or signet which have much smaller blockchains, or run on regtest where there is no blockchain to download. If you need to run on mainnet but don't want to download the blockchain, you can disable all connections on your node. Of course, most CLI commands will be useless that way.

Comment: That would work for me. I will try and see how to run my node on testnet. I read it is only like this  `bitcoind --testnet`

Answer (score 2):

You can use Bitcoin-CLI with only a partial copy of the blockchain. Obviously it will be limited in what it can do.